# How to remove unit from variable?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

I want to draw an arc of a certain length in cm, so I divide by the circumference in cm and multiply 360 to get the segment in degrees. (Is there a shortcut?)
In my MWE `b` is the unitless number I want to get from `a`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \def\a{3.14cm}
    \node[scale=0.5] at (-1,0) {\a};

    \def\b{{\a / (1cm*pi) *20}}
    \def\c{20}

    \node[scale=0.5] at (-1,1) {\b};

    \draw[very thin] (0,0) -- (\a/3,0);
    \draw[very thin] (0,0.1) -- (\b,0.1);
    %\draw[very thin] (0,0.1) -- ({\b+0.1},0.1);

    \draw[red] (1:1) arc (1:1+20:1);
    \draw[blue] (30:1) arc (30:{(30+\c)}:1);
    %\draw[green] (60:1) arc (60:{(60+\b)}:1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen from the node text and the commented lines `b` does not behave like a unitless scalar. Removing either comment yields `ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.`
How can I make `b` unitless?
[image]

Comment: Do you also want to draw the radius with the circumference? Why don't you use sin(x) and cos(x) as `\draw [red,thick,domain=0:90] plot ({cos(\x)}, {sin(\x)});`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\pgfmathsetmacro` removes units. (I replaced 20 by 2 because the plot was huge when using 20.)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \def\a{3.14cm}
    \node[scale=0.5] at (-1,0) {\a};

    \pgfmathsetmacro\b{{\a / (1cm*pi) *2}}
    \def\c{20}

    \node[scale=0.5] at (-1,1) {\b};

    \draw[very thin] (0,0) -- (\a/3,0);
    \draw[very thin] (0,0.1) -- (\b,0.1);
    \draw[very thin] (0,0.1) -- (\b+0.1,0.1);

    \draw[red] (1:1) arc (1:1+20:1);
    \draw[blue] (30:1) arc (30:{(30+\c)}:1);
    \draw[green] (60:1) arc (60:{(60+\b)}:1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]